# Does react phone input and react hook form can work together?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-phone-input-2

I make a form using react and material ui, instead of using state to store formdata , i read about react hook forms, that it can handle form submission , validation etc. for a phone number dropdown i am also using react-phone-input2, but in the console , i keep getting the error
'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')' everytime i type number in react phone input. Is there a way the react hook form and react phone input library is clashing??

````
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    watch,
    setValue,
    name
  } = useForm();
 <InputLabel
                    htmlFor="Phone"
                    className="input-label"
                    sx={{
                      minWidth: '120px',
                      fontWeight: 500,
                    }}
                  >
                    Phone
                  </InputLabel>
               
                  <ReactPhoneInput  
                  name='phone'      
  variant="outlined" 
  fullWidth 
  containerClass="phone-input-container"
  {...register('phone', {
    required: 'Phone is required',
  })}
/>```
````